# Object oriented design. What better?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I have a `Printer` class that should print a `number` and `text`. The `number` never changes for each `Client` class. I have more `Client` objects with different `number` values.

What design is better?

In the `sample1` the number sends to `print()` method as argument, therefore all `Client` objects use single `Print` object. In the `sample2` the number sends to the `Printer` constructor, therefore each `Client` object have own `Printer` object.

Please help me figure it out.

[image: UML diagram]

Comment: What about having a PrintController that can be assigned a Client and a Printer? Separating the client from the printer seems like a good idea.

Comment: Then PrintController should contain the number? I think it is redundant class. I want to know how design class methods better. Send the number to the print() method directly or the Printer can contain the number.

Comment: Is the number a unique identifier of the client?

Comment: It is only an example. The number could be an unique identifier of the client. But only print feature needs the number. May be the number will be used somewhere else.

Comment: If it is used somewhere else, in relation to the client, then I would make it an attribute of the client and give it a more meaningful name such as ClientPrinterNumber.

Comment: What is better, the sample1 that uses single Printer object, or sample2 that uses more Printer objects with the clientNumber?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185618/discussion-between---and-ross-bush).

Comment: What is number? What does it represent and what entity does it belongs to? It is the client number, or is it a print job number, or anything else? It has to be clearly defined before we know the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Number 2 seems to fit your requirements better.

In the first solution you use a "generic" `Printer`, which knows nothing about `Client`s or their numbers, therefore need the number as a parameter. This seems logical because you probably have a physical "printer" in real life and *that* does not depend on any `Client`s.

However, your object model must fit the *requirements*, **not** "real life". This is a bit confusing, because we sometimes call the "requirements" "real life". Regardless, your requirements clearly state that `Client` wants to print some text and for the client the "number" is static, i.e. irrelevant. So just make a *mental* change, that the `Printer` is not a generic printer, but a `Printer` specifically there for the `Client`s.

With this mental model the 2. solution clearly fits better.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend solution 1.

Because if the number is not a requirement for the printer it shouldn't go there. If the number is specific to clients, they should store their individual value and pass it to the printer. This makes the printer reusable in other places, where the number might change.

What if you need to query the client's number? Solution 2 makes you ask the printer about the number specific to the client, whether it is unique or not. That's not good: you are violating separation of concerns. But beside that it doesn't feel smooth, right? Solution 2 forces you to initialize the printer again or create a new instance any time the number changes (and it will as you stated).

The printer shouldn't care about the content it is printing. To make more reusable you could make the 'Print()' method to accept an `IPrintable` with a method 'GetData()'. Then the printer doesn't have to change the signature of the 'Print()' any time you add new content types or content and in this case you would also avoid too much arguments in the method's signature. So new content types just implement `IPrintable`.

Now you decided you need to print a number, a text and an additional date or timestamp? Then simply modify the `IPrintable` object or create a new implementation instead of modifying the `Printer` class itself. The `IPrintable` object could also be responsible for formatting the output. Printer shouldn't care about formatting too in order to make it more generic. Otherwise small changes require you to implement a new printer.

A printer usually has a queue to allow concurrent use by the clients. It will be a lot more difficult to implement this in case you store those kind of information directly in the printer object. Code will look not nice anymore. Better to keep associated data together e.g. inside an `IPrintable` parameter.